# Bash operators: "!" vs "-z"

Tags: bash, operators

What is the difference between the operator "!" and "-z" applied to a string?

```
#Example 1
if [ ! STRING ]; then ...

#Example 2
if [ -z STRING ]; then ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all you make use of single brackets. This implies that you are using the `test` command and not the Bash-builtin function. From the manual :

> **`test EXPRESSION`** or **`[ EXPRESSION ]`:** this exits with the status returned by `EXPRESSION`
>
> **`! EXPRESSION`:**   `test` returns **true** of `EXPRESSION` is **false**
>
> **`-z STRING`:** `test` returns **true** if the length of `STRING` is zero.

Examples:

```
$ [ -z "foo" ] && echo "zero length" || echo "non-zero length"
non-zero length
$ [ ! -z "foo" ] && echo "non-zero length" || echo "zero length"
non-zero length
$ [ -z "" ] && echo "zero length" || echo "non-zero length"
zero length
$ [ ! -z "" ] && echo "non-zero length" || echo "zero length"
zero length
```

But now you were wondering about `[ ! STRING ]`:

The manual states that `[ STRING ]` is equivalent to `[ -n STRING ]`, which tests if `STRING` has a non-zero length.  Thus `[ ! STRING ]` is equivalent to `[ -z STRING ]`.

> **`-n STRING`:**  the length of `STRING` is nonzero.
>
> **`STRING`:**   equivalent to `-n STRING`
>
> **<sub>source: `man test`</sub>**

---

**answer:**`[ ! STRING ]` is equivalent to `[ -z STRING ]`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: they're the same.

---

```
[ ! STRING ]
```

is the negation of

```
[ STRING ] # which is implicitly [ -n STRING ]
```

so `[ ! STRING ]` is true if the the length of `STRING` is <strike>not non-</strike>zero.

```
[ -z STRING ]
```

is also true if the length of `STRING` is zero.