# Not equals is not working as expected in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

Am trying to write a shell script to kill a process if it already exists in jenkins and run a jar.

Am not sure where am going wrong. I typically want to check if the processID is not null then kill the process else just print processID doesn't exist.

I have gone through some of the below links wherein they suggested to use "-z" to check null. since i wanted to check not null , so I've used [! -z $my_var] but this doesn't seem to work.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-find-out-if-a-variable-has-null-value-or-not/

In jenkins , execute shell code:

```
            BUILD_ID=do_not_kill_me
            my_var=$(pgrep -f customer);
            if [[! -z $my_var]]
            then
                kill -9 "$my_var";
                echo "PID exists and killing it";   
            else
                echo "PID is null/PID doesn't exist";
            fi
            cp -rf customer*.jar /data/dev/customer/customer.jar
            java -jar /data/dev/customer/customer.jar &
            exit
```

I want the data in "If" part to be executed but always else is getting executed.

sample output from jenkins when i click on build now,

```
        + BUILD_ID=do_not_kill_me
        + pgrep -f customer
        + my_var=15531
        + [[! -z 15531]]
        /tmp/jenkins390846207133389320.sh: 4: /tmp/jenkins390846207133389320.sh: [[!: not found
        + echo PID is null/PID doesn't exist
        PID is null/PID doesn't exist
        + cp -rf customer-management-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /data/dev/customer/customer.jar
        + exit
```

although my PID exists it return print message stating not exists.
Let me know where am going wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case, try and add spaces:

```
 if [ ! -z ${my_var} ]
```

You can see [examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51440747/6309) or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3834/7490).

Comment: The space was the issue. Thanks a lot @VonC

Comment: @Vignesh_A : In your original code, you used `[[ ]]`, not `[ ]`. But `[[!` should issue the error message `bash: [[!: command not found`, unless you have in your path an executable file with the funny name `[[!`. Since your transscript shows that you did not get an error message, I recommend that you search your PATH for such a file and remove it, to avoid problems in the future.